# What does std::vector::insert does, if it is fed by reverse iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I am populating vector keeping it ordered in the following manner

```
vector<int>::iterator it = upper_bound(arr.begin(), arr.end(), value);
arr.insert(it, value);
```

Now I would like to keep reversed order. What if I do

```
vector<int>::iterator it = upper_bound(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), value).base();
arr.insert(it, value);
```

will

```
arr.insert(it, value);
```

work correctly, i.e. put new value AFTER found entry in `arr`?

What is with complexity? How long will it take to insert element in the beginning of iteration, i.e. in the end of vector? Close to O(1) right?

---

I tried this

```
vector<int> src = {10, 1, 3, 7, 2, 100};
    vector<int> dst;

    for (auto it=src.begin(); it!=src.end(); ++it) {
        //auto it2 = upper_bound(dst.begin(), dst.end(), *it);
        vector<int>::iterator it2 = upper_bound(dst.rbegin(), dst.rend(), *it).base();
        dst.insert(it2, *it);
    }
```

and it worked, but why? If `it2` is normal iterator, then, for example when searching for `7` in `{10, 1, 3` `it2` will point to `10` and `insert` will insert `7` BEFORE `10`.

How it appears after?

---

The following code

```
int main() {

    vector<int> src = {10, 1, 3, 7, 2, 100};
    vector<int> dst;

    auto begin = src.begin();

    for (auto it=src.begin(); it!=src.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;

        //auto it2 = upper_bound(dst.begin(), dst.end(), *it);
        vector<int>::iterator it2 = upper_bound(dst.rbegin(), dst.rend(), *it).base();
        if (it2 == begin) {
            cout << "begin" << endl;
        }
        dst.insert(it2, *it);
    }

    cout << dst << endl;

}
```

prints

```
10
1
3
7
2
100
100, 10, 7, 3, 2, 1
```

i.e. it never prints "begin". But why?

Comment: Did you mean `std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::upper_bound(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), value).base();` (`.base()` added to have `iterator` from `reverse_iterator`)?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: There isn't an implicit conversion from `std::reverse_iterator<it>` to `it`, and the pointed-to element is different

Comment: You know that `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound` can take a comparer, so you might use `std::greater` instead of default `std::less`.

Comment: *"if it is fed by reverse iterator?"* It can't be given a reverse iterator, so the premise of the question is false.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I am understanding with comparator, I don't understand case with reverse iterating.

Comment: Have you look at [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) and [`base()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base)?

Comment: *"it never prints "begin""* `it2 == begin` compares iterators from different ranges, it should be `it2 == dst.begin()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `it2` is normal iterator, then, for example when searching for 7 in {10, 3, 1} `it2` will point to 10 and insert will insert 7 BEFORE 10.

Except that a reverse iterator dereferences to the value *next to* it's `base` (following from the pov of the base type, preceding from the pov of the reverse). You can observe this by dereferencing `it2` (as long as it precedes `dst.end()`), it points to 3 in that case.

Here's more intermediate output, [showing the difference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa184bcca807d2a9)

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int> src = {10, 1, 3, 7, 2, 100};
    std::vector<int> dst;

    for (int i : src) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
        auto it = upper_bound(dst.rbegin(), dst.rend(), i);
        auto it2 = it.base();
        if (it != dst.rend()) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << "first ";
        }
        if (it2 != dst.end()) {
            std::cout << *it2;
        } else {
            std::cout << "last";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        dst.insert(it2, i);
    }

    std::cout << dst << std::endl;

}
```